# BizTalk, sending SMTP message from SendPort, with attachment from ReceiveLocation

Tags: biztalk

I have a receive location from File adapter. I put a file here. Then I want to send it on mail using SMTP Adapter in Send Port. I need to attach a file which i receive in Receive Location.

Do you have any ideas how to do it. I want to try to do it without custom pipelines and orchestrations.

Comment: What have you tried, and what issue are you having?

Comment: I just did what you want in less that 5 minutes, so please give further details of what the issue is.
And why do you want to do this?   See my blog with a few reasons as to why you shouldn't do it.  https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2021/12/10/biztalk-sending-messages-via-email/